# How to Query ApexLog raw body?

Tags: apex, soql, query, rest, debug-logs

I need to find, in ApexLogs raw bodies, references to a given String value.

I know we can query the object [ApexLog fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_ApexLog.htm), by using the following code:

```
SELECT id, 
       loguserid, 
       loglength, 
       lastmodifieddate, 
       request, 
       operation, 
       application, 
       status,
       durationmilliseconds, 
       systemmodstamp, 
       starttime, 
       location 
FROM   apexlog
```

And, once we have the log ID, we can either retrieve a raw log, using the REST resource */sobjects/ApexLog/id/Body/* or even the totally not recommended trace download:

https://YourPrefix.salesforce.com/apexdebug/traceDownload.apexp?id=99999999999999YourID

Now, is it possible to query Debug Logs Bodies, directly, using a WHERE clause, to find a string reference? In which object the debug body is stored?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in ApexLog, but you can't query/filter the log itself, only the exposed metadata (e.g. status or request). You would necessarily need to download each one using the preferred API (`/sobjects/ApexLog/{id}/Body`). This limitation exists because you can't filter on the logs. You also cannot search (SOSL) on ApexLog, either, probably as a matter of performance.

Answer (score 7):

You don't name a use case, or whether there is a particular place you are integrating this from. But if it was just a matter of, "I need to get a log out and check for some string value in it," these days, I would probably prefer to use Salesforce DX to do this.

```
sfdx force:apex:log:get -i <MyLogId>
```

Using this you can also retrieve multiple logs at once...potentially all of them.

```
sfdx force:apex:log:get -n 2  <- retrieve the last 2 log files
sfdx force:apex:log:get -n 10
```

This will spit out all of the log bodies which you can then grep.

```
sfdx force:apex:log:get -n 2 | grep 'Colonial'

18:46:16.10 (20641304)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[2]|p|{"Id":"a040E000001zVStQAM","Name":"Stunning Colonial","Location__c":"API location: [42.360642 -71.110448]"}|0x5cacdf1b
18:46:35.11 (17502936)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[2]|p|{"Id":"a040E000001zVStQAM","Name":"Stunning Colonial","Location__c":"API location: [42.360642 -71.110448]"}|0x37955bc2
```

If you want context around the actual line you find, you can use `grep`'s before and after context features to get more than just the line you are looking for. For instance here, I get the line with the regex pattern, *and* 5 lines before and after each time it is found.

```
sfdx force:apex:log:get -n 2 | grep -B 5 -A 5 'Colonial'

18:46:35.11 (17280734)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2]
18:46:35.11 (17333161)|USER_DEBUG[2]|DEBUG|System.Location[getLatitude=42.335435;getLongitude=-71.106827;]
18:46:35.11 (17362725)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[2]|Bytes:5
18:46:35.11 (17384098)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[2]|Bytes:16
18:46:35.11 (17396491)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[2]|p|Property__c|true|false
18:46:35.11 (17502936)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[2]|p|{"Id":"a040E000001zVStQAM","Name":"Stunning Colonial","Location__c":"API location: [42.360642 -71.110448]"}|0x37955bc2
18:46:35.11 (17517639)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2]
18:46:35.11 (17520423)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2]
18:46:35.11 (17566892)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|System.Location[getLatitude=42.360642;getLongitude=-71.110448;]
18:46:35.11 (17597445)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[2]|Bytes:5
18:46:35.11 (17616068)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[2]|Bytes:16
--
--
18:56:25.19 (29745072)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2]
18:56:25.19 (29815343)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|System.Location[getLatitude=42.335435;getLongitude=-71.106827;]
18:56:25.19 (29877304)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[2]|Bytes:5
18:56:25.19 (29908067)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[2]|Bytes:16
18:56:25.19 (29923611)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[2]|p|Property__c|true|false
18:56:25.19 (30106839)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[2]|p|{"Id":"a040E000001zVStQAM","Name":"Stunning Colonial","Location__c":"API location: [42.360642 -71.110448]"}|0x380f42d
18:56:25.19 (30131234)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2]
18:56:25.19 (30135912)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2]
18:56:25.19 (30215204)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|System.Location[getLatitude=42.360642;getLongitude=-71.110448;]
18:56:25.19 (30269076)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[2]|Bytes:5
18:56:25.19 (30294622)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[2]|Bytes:16
```

Answer (score 1):

The following simple apex code will provide the log body, without using the tooling api callout:

```
string logId = '{alexlog_id}';
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+logId);
string logBody = String.valueOf(pageRef.getContent());
system.debug(logBody);
```

I know it's crazy - but it works!

Comment: Hi Yo Force, but in this case you already have the logId, correct?